# Errors while wrtting script

Tags: java

Write the complete java program called Temperature that includes a for loop structure, prompting the user to enter 5 temperature values. The program should add up each temperature entered within the loop and this is stored in a variable called total. Using a system statement, output the total temperature value and the average temperature value. Use the sample output below as a guide:
The total temperature =
The average temperature =

My answer is the statement below but im still getting errors:-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner temp = new Scanner (System.in);
        double total = 0;
        for(int=1;int<=5;int++);
        {
            System.out.println ("Enter temperature #" + temp +":");
            double temperature = temp.nextDouble ();
            total = temperature;

        }
        System.out.println("The total temperature =" +total);
        System.out.println("The average temperature=" +(double)(total/5));
    }
}
```

Comment: what kind of error?

Comment: Hint: to get the total, you need a sum (`+`) somewhere

Comment: change `for(int=1;int<=5;int++)` to  `for(int i=1;int<=5;i++)` and please add the error

Answer (score 0):

The OP does not state what errors you are getting exactly, but I can guess some of them are from:

```
for(int=1;int<=5;int++);
```

You cannot use `int` like that. It is a *type* and should be used like the following:

```
for(int itr = 1; itr <= 5; itr++) { ...
```

Also, the semi-colon on your for loop doesn't need to be there.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=1;i<=5;i++) {
     System.out.println ("Enter temperature #" + temp +":");
     double temperature = temp.nextDouble ();
     total += temperature;
}
```